# how does this Implicit conversion happen?

Tags: c++

how does this Implicit conversion happen?

```
class A {};
class B { public: B (A a) {} };

A a;
B b=a;
```

class B has a constructor B(A a) takes object a as a object,but inside the constructor of B, it does nothing. so how does this happens?

Answer (score 3):

The constructor of `B` which takes a parameter of type `A` gets called when you write `B b=a`. Its true that constructor of `B` does nothing with the argument `a`, but that is a different thing altogether.

Its equivalent to:

```
 B b(a); //equivalent to "B b = a;"
```

---

The syntax `B b=a` invokes the constructor of `B` which takes `A` as argument; after that what the constructor does with the argument `a`, has nothing to do with the constructor's invocation!

It is like the following case, when you write `f(100)`, you're passing 100 to `f()`; now it `f` does nothing with the `100`, its a different story. It doesn't has anything to do with the function invocation.

```
void f(int a)
{
  return;
}

f(100);
```

Comment: @Nawaz so this means if constructor B takes A as a parameter, it does not matter what this constructor do, A can be converted to B?

Comment: @ratzip: Exactly. :-)  `B b=a` invokes the constructor; after that what the constructor do with the argument, is nothing to do with constructor invocation!

Comment: @Nawaz, It confuses me, do not understand.

Comment: @ratzip: I added an explanation to my answer. See it. And let me know what you find confusing!

Comment: @Nawaz, I know B constructor takes A as a argument, but it implicit convert A to B. I am confusing this part.

Comment: @Nawaz, does the assignment constructor do this job?

Comment: @ratzip: That is not assignment. That is initialization. And this initialization causes constructor of `B` getting called, passing `a` as argument. What is confusing in it?

Comment: @Nawaz, he asked Implicit conversion, this mean A is converted to B, I think he want to know why and I also confused about it

Comment: @ratzip: `B b=a` is equivalent to `B b(a)`.  Do you find the latter confusing?

Answer (score 0):

> so how does this happens?

B(A a) gets called. Pretty much the same thing that would happen in that constructor as if b was default constructed with an empty default constructor. Default constructors on members of B are executed.

Comment: Wrong. There is no default constructor to begin with!

Comment: @Doug T: After editing the post, you're asking me, "ok what did I get wrong?"?

Comment: @Doug T: This part is still wrong : *"Default constructors on members of B are executed."*.... Also, how many default constructors do you have in a class?

Comment: @Nawaz, before I had the sentence "Pretty much the same thing that would happen in **that constructor** as if b was default constructed with an empty default constructor." My assumption being the asker knew which constructor was being called. You correctly pointed out which constructor gets called but without saying what happens.

Comment: @Nawaz, so you're telling me that if B had a `std::string` and B(A a) was called, the default constructor for B's string wouldn't be called?

Comment: @Doug: Your earlier sentence was "default constructor gets called".

Comment: 'This part is still wrong : "Default constructors on members of B are executed."' Simply not true. The phrase is fine.

Comment: @Tomalak @Nawaz I must be coffee deprived. But AFAIK, if you have a constructor, and you have members with default constructors, and you don't explicitly construct them in an initializer list, they will be default constructed for you. So if you have a `std::string` member, when your constructor is invoked, without you specifying anything in your constructor's initializer list, `std::string`'s default constructor gets invoked. What about this is wrong? When would my member not also have its default constructor invoked to invoke it?

Comment: @Doug: You are correct. My comment indicated that Nawaz's comment -- which asserted that your comment was incorrect -- was incorrect.

Comment: @Tomalak oh double quotes, I see now. Hope your conquest of the Federation proceeds smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because in C++, while calling constructor, implicit conversion for one parameter is allowed.

For eg. if you have the following class:

```
class A
{
    int a;
    public:
           A(int _a):a(_a){}
} ;
```

Then, the following statement is valid:

```
A ob = 5 ;
equivalent to `A ob(int(5)) ;`
```

Drawing analogy from this example, in your case, `B b = a;` can be expanded as `B b(A(a));`

Further, you can read about **explicit** keyword in C++

Note: The example above is just for reference so please ignore the equivalent notations for syntactical validation

Answer (score 0):

Conversion from A to B means, "construct an instance of B, passing an instance of A as a constructor parameter".

Whether B actually *uses* that instance of A to do anything in the constructor is irrelevant. It's still a conversion, whether or not the value of the A instance has any effect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

`B`'s constructor doesn't *need* to do anything.

By creating the [non-explicit] constructor that takes an `A` as a parameter, you're making `A` convertible to `B`.

The constructor body is where you can specify behaviours that should be performed upon such a construction, but since you didn't write anything there (and nothing in the `ctor-initializer`, either), nothing happens.

The actual construction of the `B` still occurs, as usual, thanks to the language.

You just get the `B`, as if you'd created it through *any other constructor* you could come up with, either without arguments or with arguments that you never get around to using.

<sup>BTW, you should probably accept `A& const`, not `A`.</sup>